# Diagonal background for Bootstrap row

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

[Background that I want to do.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bl6Ga.png) I have a row with two columns, how to make a diagonal fill two colors?
Fill from left to right, with a shift down.

Comment: Try to share your tried efforts! like a working code snippet ! Or atleast an image, of what exactly you want! Otherwise, your question will be flagged by someone

Comment: As I wrote, I want to create a diagonal fill. Structure container> row> col-lg-6 * 2 standard, I thought that here understand structure.

Comment: I think, this will help you: 
http://stackoverflow.com/a/14552183/3161291

Comment: Thank you. But if I'm not mistaken, there can not be offset.

Comment: http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without an image, add:

```
.row {background: linear-gradient(to right bottom, #HEXCOLORCODE1 50%, #HEXCOLOR2 50%); }
```

Replace #HEXCOLORCODE1, and #HEXCOLORCODE2 with your desired color codes.

Comment: Thank you)
I wrote on the basis of comments here this code:
background: linear-gradient(205deg, #f5f5f5 55%, #e5e4e4 30%); }

Answer (score 0):

It's tricky, but here is my suggested solution:
Create your diagonal background image in 2x width.
Use CSS horizontal background-position, and set the value to 0 for the first column, and 50% for the next one.
You also need to use CSS background-size attribute to make the half of the image shown at a time on all device sizes.

Comment: another approch, and the easier one, is not to use any background for the cols (transparent), but assign the diagonal background to the row itself.

Comment: To implement this without pictures possible?
I added a picture to understand.